# window.navigate vs response.redirect, whats the difference?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, response.redirect

What's the difference between `window.navigate` and `response.redirect`? I have tried using `response.redirect("URL")` but it didn't work when I used `window.navigate(URL)` it worked!

What's the difference between the two? I know that one is used in Java and the other is used in JavaScript but what's their use cases?

```
<body>

<%
    HttpSession sess = request.getSession(true);

    if (sess.getAttribute("username") == null
            || sess.getAttribute("password") == null) {
%>
<script>
window.navigate("login.jsp");
</script>
<%      
    } 
%>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

One causes the server to emit an HTTP redirect.

The other requires the server send an entire HTML document to the browser, the browser to parse the HTML, the browser to execute the JavaScript … and then breaks the back button.